# Project Euler #22 - Names Scores

Tags: python, programming-challenge, python-3.x

I programmed [Problem #22](https://projecteuler.net/problem=22) from Project Euler in Python. It works but I want to know if it really is pythonic enough.

> Using names.txt (right click and 'Save Link/Target As...'), a 46K text
>   file containing over five-thousand first names, begin by sorting it
>   into alphabetical order. Then working out the alphabetical value for
>   each name, multiply this value by its alphabetical position in the
>   list to obtain a name score.
>
> For example, when the list is sorted into alphabetical order, COLIN,
>   which is worth 3 + 15 + 12 + 9 + 14 = 53, is the 938th name in the
>   list. So, COLIN would obtain a score of 938 × 53 = 49714.
>
> What is the total of all the name scores in the file?

```
from itertools import count 

FILE = "e022.txt"
CHAR_OFFSET = ord('A') - 1

def parse(file):
    """Return the read in list"""
    with open(file) as fid:
        return fid.read().replace('"',"").split(',')

def score_name(name):
    """Returns the score of a single name"""
    return sum(ord(char) - CHAR_OFFSET for char in list(name))

def score_names(names):
    """Returns the score of the list"""
    return sum(ind*score_name(name) for (ind, name) in zip(count(1),sorted(names)))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    print(score_names(parse(FILE)))
```

Please feel free to critic me on it. One thing I wasn't sure about: In the file parser, did I need to make the `with` guard or is this not needed when encapsulated in a function?

Furthermore, the global variable `FILE` is in a place where it is easy accessible, but let's say we would import it as a module and wouldn't need it. Should I move it down to the `main` guard and loose a bit of overview?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Your code is split into small functions and looks nice.

A few things could be done in a better way.

`zip(count(1),sorted(names)` can be rewritten with the [`enumerate` builtin](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate) : `enumerate(sorted(names), start=1)`.

You can iterate directly over strings so you don't need to use a list in `list(name)`.

You don't need parenthesis in `for (ind, name) in`.

To answer your question :

- `FILE` could easily be moved behind the main guard so I'd put it there. Had it been the smallest of the issues, I would have left it where it currently is.
- for the `with`, I consider it to be a good habit to put it. Also, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1834556/does-a-file-object-automatically-close-when-its-reference-count-hits-zero) should answer your solution.

Comment: Thank you for this input. I didn't know about `enumerate`, what a nice tool and of course you're also right with `list`. I'm not sure if I got exactly the point with `with`, it is good to do it but not necessary? Since it leaves the file identifier leaves the scope anyway and calls the destructor?

Comment: @magu_ Did you notice that the word "this" links to a SO question that discusses the `with` matter?

Answer (score 6):

A few minor things on top of [@Josay](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/9452/josay)'s review.

#### PEP8 violations

[PEP8](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) is the official coding style guide of Python.

- Put a space after commas in parameter lists, for example `.replace('"', "")` instead of `.replace('"',"")`
- Put spaces around operators, for example `ind * score_name(name)` instead of `ind*score_name(name)`
- Put 2 blank lines in front of method definitions

#### Naming

`fid` is a bit unusual name for a file object. I'd recommend `fh` ("file handle") or `fd` ("file descriptor")

The methods `score_name` and `score_names` have too similar names.
It's good to avoid names differ only by one letter.
It would be slightly less confusing and more readable to rename `score_names` to `score_name_list`.
This may be a matter of taste though, and not a big problem.

Comment: I don't see how `fd` is an improvement over `fid`. Surely such short, abbreviated variable names aren't encouraged.

Comment: Thank you for your comment's. I completly agree with all of them. `fid` commes more from matlab but since it is actually a handle and not an identifier an other name should be better. Maybe `file` fits the bill.

Comment: @RubberDuck having seen `fd` and `fh` hundreds of times, when I see it again my brain recognizes without thinking. When I see `fid`, it's new, so I pause for a mental cycle, then for another to figure out why it's called that way. "file id" was my guess, but since I've never seen anybody calling it like that, I'm not sure if the guess is right. Only after the OP's comment I see it's the right guess, but it's an odd name. Short variable names are perfectly acceptable in some cases, I believe this is one of those.

Comment: Hey @magu_, `file` wouldn't fit the bill in Python 2, where it was the name of a builtin. Not sure about Python 3.

Comment: Okay @janos fair enough. Every language has their idioms (I can't seem to stop using `rst` for recordset no matter how hard I try.) It was just odd for an outsider to see.

Comment: @janos I personally don't mind shadowing `file` just because it's a pointless builtin.