# Project Euler 22: Names scores alternative

Tags: python, algorithm, programming-challenge

Can someone tell me how to improve my following python code.

Code:

```
a = open('/home/Username/1st few programms/names.txt')

for y in a:
    c = y.split(",")
    c.sort()

dict = {'"':0, "A": 1, "B": 2,"C": 3,"D": 4, "E": 5,"F": 6,"G": 7,"H": 8,"I": 9,"J": 10,"K": 11,"L": 12,"M": 13,"N": 14,"O": 15,"P": 16,"Q": 17,"R": 18, "S": 19, "T": 20, "U": 21, "V": 22,"W": 23,"X": 24, "Y": 25, "Z": 26}


sum = 0
for x in range(len(c)):
    localsum = 0
    for y in c[x]:
        localsum += dict[y]
    sum += localsum*(x+1)
print sum
```

Problem statement:

> Using names.txt, a 46K text file containing over five-thousand first
>   names, begin by sorting it into alphabetical order. Then working out
>   the alphabetical value for each name, multiply this value by its
>   alphabetical position in the list to obtain a name score.
>
> For example, when the list is sorted into alphabetical order, COLIN,
>   which is worth 3 + 15 + 12 + 9 + 14 = 53, is the 938th name in the
>   list. So, COLIN would obtain a score of 938 × 53 = 49714.
>
> What is the total of all the name scores in the file?

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! As we all want to make our code more efficient or improve it in one way or another, try to write a title that summarizes what your code does, not what you want to get out of a review. For examples of good titles, check out [Best of Code Review 2014 - Best Question Title Category](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/q/3883/23788) You may also want to read [How to get the best value out of Code Review - Asking Questions](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/a/2438/41243).

Comment: Also what format is `names.txt` in?

Comment: You should name your post according to the problem statement, which I regcognize to be "Project Euler 22: Names Score". This problem has been reviewed twice for Python, [here](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/73832/) and [here](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/106393/). I advice you to read those as well, as answers provided here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`a`, `dict`, `c` and `sum` are all problematic names, for two different reasons. Single character variable names should be used sparingly, really only in brief contexts where the intent is quite clear like `for i in range(10)` where it's obvious that `i` is an integer and follows `for` loop conventions. `for y in a` is very unclear because you haven't made it obvious what `y` is or should be, and `a` would be much harder to follow if not for the fact that it's declared just above. Even so the choice of letters seems totally arbitrary. I'd replace `a` with `f` for file, since it's localised.

The other naming issue is that using the names `dict` and `sum` are actually overwriting builtin functions and should be avoided, especially as I'm going to suggest that you use `sum`, which you can't do if it's been overwritten.

Also instead of using a plain `open`, you should use `with open()`. That's Python's context manager which handles file closing for you. It ensures that a file is always closed correctly, even if an error arises or you don't call `file.close()`. Note, you *didn't* call `a.close()` so clearly this is useful:

```
with open('/home/Username/1st few programms/names.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
        names = line.split(",")
        names.sort()
```

Next, this code you're using makes no sense. You're iterating over each `line` in the file but just creating a new list of names each time. If all the names are stored on one line then this works but is redundant, and I'd instead suggest this:

```
with open('/home/Username/1st few programms/names.txt') as f:
    names = f.read().split(",")
names.sort()
```

`read()` will just read the full string of the file in so that then `split` can separate it based on commas. If you do have names on multiple lines, then you want the loop but you want to add more values to `names` each time:

```
names = []
with open('/home/Username/1st few programms/names.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
        names += line.split(",")
names.sort()
```

The algorithm that determines a person's score is quite unusual, so it would actually be best to create a function for it. One that takes a name and position in the list and returns their score. It can do largely what your inner loop does:

```
def name_score(index, name):
    localsum = 0
    for character in name:
        localsum += char_points[character]
    return localsum * (index + 1)
```

However, this is one of the places I'm going to suggest you use `sum`. You can pass a generator expression into `sum` to do this calculation efficiently in one line. A generator expression is a for loop like expression, here's how it'd look for this function:

```
def name_score(index, name):
    return sum(char_points[character] for character in name) * (index + 1)
```

You can see how there's the same `for _ in` syntax as before, just that now it's collapsed into one line. You no longer need to have a `localsum` and `sum` is faster than using a `for` loop.

Now with this function, the main loop is simplified to:

```
sum = 0
for i in range(len(names)):
    sum += name_score(i, names[i])
print sum
```

First though, let's get rid of `names[i]` as that's ugly. Use Python's `enumerate` function that allows you to both get the indices and values of a list together, like this:

```
for i, name in enumerate(names):
    sum += name_score(i, name)
```

This is much cleaner now, but we can also use `sum` in this case to remove your whole loop, in fact it can skip straight to printing the sum:

```
print sum(name_score(i, name) for i, name in enumerate(names))
```

Again, this is both more readable and much faster. This also means that you no longer have a `sum` value that needs to be renamed.

Answer (score 2):

Try these 3 statements instead of the first 3 lines in your code, it should work

```
a = open('names.txt','r')
k = a.read()
c = k.split(",")
c.sort()
```

And instead of actually typing out the whole dictionary, you can ask python to do it for you, like this

```
dict={}
mynum=1
allTheLetters = string.uppercase
for i in allTheLetters:
    dict[i]=mynum
    mynum+=1
```

imports :

```
import string
```

Remove the first for loop, it's useless.
In your code you don't read the data inside the file at all, using the handler (`a`) use the `read()` function to read out data. Now the object `k`, has all the data, upon that you `split` the data considering comma(`,`) as the delimiter. object (`c`) receives it and you `sort` it out. And the rest is your problem's logic which you've got it right!